# SKAction Follow path change start point

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skaction

In my game i move many skspritenode along the same cgpath by :

```
[SKAction followPath:APath asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:68]
```

If i add in scene all my skpritenodes at the same time they overlapping during followpath animation, so i have to add each sprite with some delay... In this way the sprites can't overlap but during the game i have  "jittering" every time i had one of this sprite. I use something like this:

```
 SKAction *InsertSpriteAction=[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction performSelector:@selector(AddSprite) onTarget:self],[SKAction waitForDuration:0.5]]]];
```

and to add the sprite:

```
-(void)AddSprite{

if (NumberofSprite<50) {

    SKSpriteNode *Sprite=[SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"sprite.png"];
    Sprite.size=CGSizeMake(8, 8);
    Sprite.position=CGPointMake(1320, 570);

    [_worldNode addChild:Sprite];
    NSMutableArray *textures = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        NSString *textureName =
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sprite%i", i];
        SKTexture *texture =[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:textureName];
        [textures addObject:texture];
    }

    SKAction *spriteAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:textures timePerFrame:0.2];

    SKAction *repeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:spriteAnimation];
    [Sprite runAction:repeat];

    [Sprite runAction: [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction followPath:APath asOffset:NO orientToPath:YES duration:68]]];

    NumberofSprite++;

}
else{
    [self removeActionForKey:@"addingsprites"];
}
```

}

How i can start my sprites at different point along the path? With many startpoint in the same path i can add all my sprite at once during level loading and start a follow path without overlappings...

Comment: spriteNode/textureWithImageNamed: are slow operations, you should at least preload and cache the textures array, better yet create a pool for sprite nodes to be able to re-use them. It looks like you have a limit of 50 sprites so simply create them all up-front and change their hidden property to remove them from play.

Comment: thanks this is an improvment that i can try, but even i create all the sprite at the same time i have to use anyway a method with a delay. All the sprites are added in the same path and if they starts at the same time they overlap in one "multi-layer" sprite... is not possible to start my followpath animation with a different point each time?

Comment: you can add a waitforduration action with runblock in a sequence which then adds the path walking actions. Walking the path & creating the sprites doesn't have to be done synchronously.